# Tester at Jdeveloper 12c R2

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using Jdeveloper 12c R2, Version 12.2.1.1.0
and facing an issue when running application module .
if any view object has any kind of warning, it doesn't run the Tester.
unlike JDeveloper 11 ,it shows which VO has the issue.

my question is there any way to show log while running AM .
so i can figure which vo has the issue??

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to model project properties.
2. Select Run/Debug node then click on pencil to edit Default which is in the right side under Run configurations.
3. In java options add

   -Duser.timezone=UTC -Djbo.debugoutput=console